# Geodesic distance in graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading a paper that deals with networks/graphs. In the paper they mention the term 'geodesic distance'. I'm not able to understand what does it mean. I hope if you can explain it to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geodesic of two vertices in the graph is the shortest path between them. In an unweighted graph, this is the edge count of the shortest path.